# Flask Docker image not finding config file

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a Flask application which works fine in a venv, but fails as a Docker image because the class-based config file cannot be found.

```
|app
  |__init__.py
|main.py
|Dockerfile
|config.py
```

The **init**.py file:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

if app.config["ENV"] == "development":
    app.config.from_object("config.DevelopmentConfig")
elif app.config["ENV"] == "production":
    app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')
else:
    app.config.from_object("config.DevelopmentConfig")
```

Stripped down config file:

```py
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

class ProductionConfig():
    ...

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    ...
```

Error message:
`werkzeug.utils.ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config.ProductionConfig'. Possible reasons are:`

Docker file adapted from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers)

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV PORT 8080

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
# RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Things I've tried:

1. Placing the config file in the app directory
2. Including `app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')` below the `from_object`
3. Following the `instance` structure at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/

Any help to unpick this is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us Dockerfile, right now we don't even know if you copy the config.py file over or not. | + Why do you have app folder that is a package but everything else is in some non-package parent directory? Of course it cannot find `config.py` to import, it's in a non-related directory. Do you know how python import works? How packaging works?

Comment: What's your python version? Currently flask is only supporting versions over 3.7.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. Added.
I'm running Python 3.9.13

Comment: I vaguely understand it, but still working through the books.

Comment: The folder structure was based off various tutorials, but good to know if it's not recommended